# Why is python's serial.read, serial.read_until returning garbage after 4 bytes?

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I am using **Serial.write** to send a command to a device at work (which works fine).

After I successfully send data to the external device, I receive an `8-byte` response back which I am trying to read on python. I know what the 8-byte should look like because I am using an `oscilloscope` in `serial protocol mode`, and also `realTerminal`.

The first four bytes that my python program reads are correct, but then I get garbage.  It doesn't matter what `ser.read` command I use.

Here is the code and the output:

```
    import serial
    import time

    ser = serial.Serial(port='COM10',baudrate=38400,timeout=1)

    wakeupSAA232 = b'\x0D'
    ser.write(wakeupSAA232)


    time.sleep(0.5)


    sendData = bytearray([170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 0, 0])

    ser.write(sendData)

    #s = ser.read_until('\r')

    s = ser.read(8)

    print(s)
```

I know that I SHOULD be reading:

`00 00 00 F8 0A 14 16 0D`   (8 bytes) which are in hex

But here is the **OUTPUT:**

`b'\x00\x00\x00\xf8\n\x04\x07\r'`

If I run the program again. **OUTPUT:**
`b'\x00\x00\x00\xf8\n\x94\x96\r'`

Every time the program is run, I get different garbage for (what should be) the last 4 bytes.

The first 4 bytes are correct (the `x00\x00\x00\xf8`).  The rest is garbage that doesn't match my scope or terminal data.

8 bytes of Hex data on scope:
[image: 8 bytes of Hex data on scope]

8 bytes of Hex data on terminal:
[image: 8 bytes of Hex data on terminal]

I have tried to search for my issue online, but I need some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to review the protocol of your device.

Before you do that, you should note that the second chunk of the frame you are receiving might not be garbage after all.

Python works with Unicode, but unless instructed to display them in hexadecimal, it will replace them with their ASCII equivalent. So if you want to how them as hex, just do:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf8\n\x94\x96\r'.hex()
```

It will give you:

```
'000000f80a04070d'
```

And:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf8\n\x94\x96\r'.hex()
```

gives:

```
'000000f80a94960d'
```

There are still some differences compared to what you got on your scope and RealTerm but if you review the protocol it might make more sense now. Maybe some bytes on the frame (0x14, 0x16) change to represent something meaningful, like message number.

Comment: Since my first 4 bytes were reading properly (and appeared to be displayed in hex),  I didn't put much thought into pythons default display format (Unicode as you mentioned).  There is obviously overlap between Hexadecimal and Unicode.

Seems so obvious now.

Thank you very much!

Comment: good to hear. I'm glad what I wrote was helpful. I think everyone had their own: *what is that weird crap?* moment. Your question is very informative and complete with the scope screenshot and all, if you think the answer is useful you can mark it as solved.